# Own float object without numbering in caption

Tags: floats, numbering, captions, newfloat

I would like to define my own float object because I want it to be separated from figure and table. So I tried to use `\newfloat`using the float package. It works fine for me but there is a numbering whenever `\caption` is used.
I tried to avoid this by using the caption package and `\caption*`. In this case the caption looks exactly the way I want it to look like but the objects do not appear when using `\listof`.
Is there any way to remove the numbering of the float objects but still be able to display them when using `\listof`?

Here is a short version of what I tried:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
   \newfloat{Example}{htb}{qcl}
   \begin{Example}
      \centering
       Here is where the content would be.
      \caption{Caption should not have any number or label}
   \end{Example}    
   \listof{Example}{Examples}
\end{document}
```

This one shows the numbering what I does not want.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
    \newfloat{Example}{htb}{qcl}
    \begin{Example}
        \centering
        Here is where the content would be.
        \caption*{Caption should not have any number or label}
    \end{Example}   
    \listof{Example}{Examples}
\end{document}
```

And this one does not include any numbering but results in an empty listof.

I would appreciate any answers!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the option `labelformat=empty` for this particular floating environment and use the regular `\caption` command (instead of `\caption*`). For example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{Example}{htb}{qcl}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[Example]{labelformat=empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{Example}
        \centering
        Here is where the content would be.
        \caption{Caption should not have any number or label}
    \end{Example}   
    \listof{Example}{Examples}
\end{document}
```