# Change text box to single column in a multicolumn document

Tags: positioning, overleaf, two-column, box

I am trying to change a text box present within a multicolumn to onecolumn. But when I add     `\begin{multicols}{1}` within `box` it doesn't change to one column. For instance, for figures one could use `\begin{figure*}`.

The following is the example

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry} % for PAPER & MARGIN
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}        % for COLORED BOXES (tikz and xcolor included)
\usepackage{mathspec}               % for FONTS
\usepackage{setspace}               % for LINE SPACING
\usepackage{multicol}               % for MULTICOLUMNS

\setmainfont{Noto Sans}[
    Kerning = On,
    Mapping = tex-text,
    Numbers = Uppercase, 
    BoldFont = Noto Sans SemiBold
]                           % setting the font as Noto Sans
\setlength\parindent{0pt}   % killing indentation for all the text
\setstretch{1.3}            % setting line spacing to 1.3
\setlength\columnsep{0.25in} % setting length of column separator
\pagestyle{empty}           % setting pagestyle to be empty


\definecolor{main}{HTML}{5989cf}    % setting main color to be used
\definecolor{sub}{HTML}{cde4ff}     % setting sub color to be used

\tcbset{
    sharp corners,
    colback = white,
    before skip = 0.2cm,    % add extra space before the box
    after skip = 0.5cm      % add extra space after the box
}                           % setting global options for tcolorbox

% You can copy any following box you like to your code.

\newtcolorbox{boxA}{
    fontupper = \bf,
    boxrule = 1.5pt,
    colframe = black % frame color
}

\begin{document}
{\LARGE Simple Box} % inspired by https://saruwakakun.com/html-css/reference/box
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{boxA}
It is just a frame surrounded by a slightly thick line. A simple monochrome design might be fine, but when you want a gorgeous look, it's a bit unsatisfactory.
\end{boxA}
\begin{boxA}
It is just a frame surrounded by a slightly thick line. A simple monochrome design might be fine, but when you want a gorgeous look, it's a bit unsatisfactory.
\end{boxA}

\begin{boxA}
\begin{multicols}{1}
It is just a frame surrounded by a slightly thick line. A simple monochrome design might be fine, but when you want a gorgeous look, it's a bit unsatisfactory.
\end{multicols}
\end{boxA}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want a float environment... but if you do there's https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565226/own-float-object-without-numbering-in-caption

Comment: Actually why don't you just stop the multicols 2 environment?

Comment: @user202729 I am using this in a manuscript which is has two-column

Answer (score 1):

> I am using this in a manuscript which is two-column

I have a couple solutions, but none of them are "ideal" and each has its drawbacks.
First, let me give the example where I will run the solutions (copy and then paste the solution(s) in the line after the `% Put solution in here !`):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry} 
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}        
%\usepackage{multicol}               % for MULTICOLUMNS

\usepackage{lipsum}


\tcbset{
    sharp corners,
    colback = white,
    before skip = 0.2cm,    
    after skip = 0.5cm      
}                           % setting global options for tcolorbox

\newtcolorbox{boxA}{
    fontupper = \bf,
    boxrule = 1.5pt,
    colframe = black % frame color
}


\begin{document}
{\LARGE Simple Box}

\begin{boxA}
It is just a frame surrounded by a slightly thick line. A simple monochrome design might be fine, but when you want a gorgeous look, it's a bit unsatisfactory.
\end{boxA}

\begin{boxA}
It is just a frame surrounded by a slightly thick line. A simple monochrome design might be fine, but when you want a gorgeous look, it's a bit unsatisfactory.
\end{boxA}

\lipsum[1-1]

% Put solution in here !

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

**Solution 1:**

Uncomment `\usepackage{multicol}` (just for this solution). Then at the start of the desired page, use the command `\onecolumn`. Then use the `multicols` environment to make the page have two columns. To make the box one column, simply end and begin the environment before and after the box. This has the advantage of getting the box exactly where you want it.

[image]

For this solution only, I will provide the example from `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}`.

```
\begin{document}
\onecolumn
{\LARGE Simple Box}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{boxA}
It is just a frame surrounded by a slightly thick line. A simple monochrome design might be fine, but when you want a gorgeous look, it's a bit unsatisfactory.
\end{boxA}

\begin{boxA}
It is just a frame surrounded by a slightly thick line. A simple monochrome design might be fine, but when you want a gorgeous look, it's a bit unsatisfactory.
\end{boxA}

\lipsum[1-1]

% Put solution in here
\end{multicols}

\begin{boxA}
It is just a frame surrounded by a slightly thick line. A simple monochrome design might be fine, but when you want a gorgeous look, it's a bit unsatisfactory.
\end{boxA}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum

\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\twocolumn
\end{document}
```

***Drawbacks:*** You get an error message:

```
Package multicol Warning: May not work with the twocolumn option on input line 141.
```

Also, it might be difficult to know wehere exactly the page should start and end. The commands `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` begins a new page. If you place them at the wrong spot, it might look awkward (worst case: one word only on a single page).

Nonetheless, I personally think this may be the best solution.

**Solution 2:**

Use the `minipage` environment to create a minipage that spans the width of the page (`\textwidth`):

```
\vspace{\parskip}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{boxA}
It is just a frame surrounded by a slightly thick line. A simple monochrome design might be fine, but when you want a gorgeous look, it's a bit unsatisfactory.
\end{boxA}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{\parskip}
```

***Drawbacks:*** The text in the second column will overlay the box. This works best if you only have text in the first column. To ensure this you can use the commands `\clearpage` or `\newpage` after the box.

[image]

Side note: I used this solution to make a table of contents in the twocolumn version of `elsarticle` after the abstract.

**Solution 3:**

Wrap it inside a `\twocolumn[]` and use the `\begin{@twocolumnfalse}`.

```
\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\begin{boxA}
It is just a frame surrounded by a slightly thick line. A simple monochrome design might be fine, but when you want a gorgeous look, it's a bit unsatisfactory.
\end{boxA}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
```

***Drawbacks:*** This will start a new page (the `\twocolumn` command does this). However, the rest of the new page will be two columns and filled with text.

[image]

**Solution 4:**

Put it inside a `table*` or `figure*` environment.

```
\begin{table*}[!ht]
\begin{boxA}
It is just a frame surrounded by a slightly thick line. A simple monochrome design might be fine, but when you want a gorgeous look, it's a bit unsatisfactory.
\end{boxA}
\end{table*}
```

***Drawbacks:*** No or little conrol where the box ends up. In this example it ended up in the center of page 2. If we add another `\lipsum` after the box, it ends up on the top of page 2 (same as solution 2). I recommend using this if the position of the box is not that important.

**Solution 5:**

Use the `\onecolumn` command and the `\twocolumn` before and after the box. This, however, comes with a huge drawback.

```
\onecolumn
\begin{boxA}
It is just a frame surrounded by a slightly thick line. A simple monochrome design might be fine, but when you want a gorgeous look, it's a bit unsatisfactory.
\end{boxA}
\twocolumn
```

***Drawback:*** The `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` commands starts new pages (same as using the commans `\clearpage` and `\newpage`). The result is that the box will be on its own page. In many cases not desirable.

[image]

**Other comments:**

It does *not* help putting the `multicol` environment *inside* the box as you did in your MWE. This will only change the text *within* the box and not the environment the box is in itself. It would be better to switch the positions of `\begin{box}` and `\begin{multicol}{1}`. Would this have worked? No, unfortuantley not. This is because it is already inside a twocolumn environment (multicol 2) in your MWE.

I reduced your example and removed some code that was not necessary to explain the solutions.